# Javascript run properly if the html opened locally. but it fails if accessed from http-server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html which embed a web widget from tradingview.com, the html file looks like below:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<span id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Economic Calendar by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-events.js">
{
  "width": "510",
  "height": "600"
}
</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

If you copy this code into jsfiddle, it can show a finance widget properly.
If I open the file locally, everything works fine too and the widget show up. But If I put this file under a http-server running on my machine and access it from http://localhost, the file can be loaded but the widget does not display. Looks like the script does not run properly in this mode.

Any idea what can cause this type of issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: That object doesn't do much

Comment: @Bart: When a `script` element has a `src`, the inline content of the `script` element is not executed and is considered "documentation". Presumably the tradingview.com script reads the contents and uses them to initialize some state. (Not how I would oo it, but...)

Comment: It does a lot if you run it in jsfiddle. it show a web widget which display the economic calendar that announce important economic data.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the origin of the widget is here: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/economic-calendar/

Comment: Interesting, it looks like their script has some checks on whether it's `localhost` or not and also the origin of the script, so you can't just download their file, modify and use. ATM I can't really tell whether that's the problem though. If you simply rewrite localhost as something else (use ngrok or something), the website would work.

Comment: @Nelson: Thank you so much. It is certainly related to the localhost as you point out. If I use the ip directly, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run code inside of a script tag that has a `src` tag. If you read the w3 documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp you'll see that they state:

> **Note:** If the "src" attribute is present, the  element must be
>   empty.

Another thing you may want to check is to make sure that you can open secure web links on the server you are testing this on. Because the src of the file is `https` you need to make sure there aren't any issues with handling secure external links. You could try making a local copy of the file and running that locally and see if you still get the same results. If it starts working then its not pulling the file correctly from the external source.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. It does run properly if open as a local file. As Nelson point out, it seems the script check the 'localhost' for some reason. If I use ip instead of localhost, it works fine.